# SerialPorts and WaitForMultipleObjects

Tags: winapi, serial-port, waitformultipleobjects

I'm having some problems with serial ports in a cross-platform application (with Linux embedded and actual embedded targets), which also works on Windows to make development easier. This is about the Windows implementation.

The implementation of the serial protocol is, therefore, targetted at a mixture of OS- and non-OS systems and I won't touch the implementation itself. I'd like to make it compatible with the existing implementation. If that fails within reasonable time, I'll just make a separate thread for serial reading.

OK, basically the implementation opens the serial port, registers the file descriptor in our IO system (which uses `epoll` on Linux and `WaitForMultipleObjects` on Windows) and then, basically, just waits for all handles and does whatever required. So we want to read from the serial port when the handle is signaled for reading. Unfortunately on Windows, you can't specify if you're waiting for read or write, so I thought I'd use the following solution:

- `CreateFile` with `FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED`
- `SetCommMask` with `EV_RXCHAR`
- Create an `OVERLAPPED` structure with a manual reset event
- Call `WaitCommEvent` with said `OVERLAPPED` structure, which usually returns `ERROR_IO_PENDING`

That's the basic setup. I register the event handle instead of the file handle to wait on. When the handle is signalled, I do the following:

- `ReadFile`
- If successful, `ResetEvent` and call `WaitCommEvent` again

It seems, however, that if you specify `FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED`, you *must* use overlapped IO also for reading and writing. So I thought that whenever `ReadFile` or `WriteFile` return `ERROR_IO_PENDING`, I'll just wait for the IO with `WaitForSingleObject` and `GetOverlappedResult`. It seems that I don't get into that though. It seems to work basically, but sometimes it crashes on one of the `ResetEvent` calls, as if the overlapped was still active (though I guess it still shouldn't crash).

So, the actual question. Can this be done as I want it? Is there a problem with the approach in general, or should it work? Or is using yet another thread the only good solution? The communication is already in a separate thread, so it would be at least three threads then.

---

I'll try to post as much code as needed, though it is reduced from the actual code which contains a lot of things not directly related to serial reading.

```
SerialPort::SerialPort(const std::string &filename)
{
    fd = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    m_ov = new OVERLAPPED(); // Pointer because header shouldn't include Windows.h.
    memset(m_ov, 0, sizeof(OVERLAPPED));
    m_waitHandle = m_ov->hEvent = CreateEvent(0, true, 0, 0);
}

SerialPort::~SerialPort(void)
{
    Close();
    CloseHandle(m_ov->hEvent);
    delete m_ov;
}
```

The constructor is called in a separate thread, which later calls Open:

```
bool SerialPort::Open(void)
{
    if (fd != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        return true;
    fd = CreateFile(filename.c_str(), GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED, NULL);
    if (fd != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        DCB dcb;
        ZeroMemory(&dcb, sizeof(DCB));

        COMMTIMEOUTS timeouts = {0};
        timeouts.ReadIntervalTimeout = TimeOut();
        timeouts.ReadTotalTimeoutConstant = TimeOut();
        timeouts.ReadTotalTimeoutMultiplier = TimeOut() / 5;
        if (timeouts.ReadTotalTimeoutMultiplier == 0) {
            timeouts.ReadTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 1;
        }

        if (!SetCommTimeouts(fd, &timeouts)) {
            DebugBreak();
        }
        SetCommMask(fd, EV_RXCHAR);
        InitWait();

        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

void SerialPort::InitWait()
{
    if (WaitForSingleObject(m_ov->hEvent, 0) == WAIT_OBJECT_0) {
        return; // Still signaled
    }         
    DWORD dwEventMask;
    if (!WaitCommEvent(fd, &dwEventMask, m_ov)) {
        // For testing, I have some prints here for the different cases.
    }
}
```

Via a rather long chain, the thread then calls `WaitForMultipleObjects` on m_`waitHandle`, which is the same as the `hEvent` member of the `OVERLAPPED` structure. This is done in a loop, and there are several other handles in the list, that's why this is different from the typical solution where you have a thread exclusively reading from the serial port. I have, basically, no control about the loop, that's why I try to do the `WaitCommEvent` (within `InitWait`) at just the right time.

When the handle is signaled, the ReadData method is called by the thread:

```
int SerialPort::ReadData(void *buffer, int size)
{
    if (fd != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        // Timeouts are reset here to MAXDWORD/0/0, not sure if necessary.
        DWORD dwBytesRead;
        OVERLAPPED ovRead = {0};
        ovRead.hEvent = CreateEvent(0, true, 0, 0);
        if (ReadFile(fd, buffer, size, &dwBytesRead, &ovRead)) {
            if (WaitForSingleObject(m_ov->hEvent, 0) == WAIT_OBJECT_0) {
                // Only reset if signaled, because we might get here because of a timer.
                ResetEvent(m_waitHandle);
                InitWait();
            }
            CloseHandle(ovRead.hEvent);
            return dwBytesRead;
        } else {
            if (GetLastError() == ERROR_IO_PENDING) {
                WaitForSingleObject(ovRead.hEvent, INFINITE);
                GetOverlappedResult(fd, &ovRead, &dwBytesRead, true);
                InitWait();
                CloseHandle(ovRead.hEvent);
                return dwBytesRead;
            }
        }
        InitWait();
        CloseHandle(ovRead.hEvent);
        return -1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

The write is done as follows, without syncing:

```
int SerialPort::WriteData(const void *buffer, int size)
{
    if (fd != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        DWORD dwBytesWritten;
        OVERLAPPED ovWrite = {0};
        ovWrite.hEvent = CreateEvent(0, true, 0, 0);
        if (!WriteFile(fd, buffer, size, &dwBytesWritten, &ovWrite)) {
            if (GetLastError() == ERROR_IO_PENDING) {
                WaitForSingleObject(ovWrite.hEvent, INFINITE);
                GetOverlappedResult(fd, &ovWrite, &dwBytesWritten, true);
                CloseHandle(ovWrite.hEvent);
                return dwBytesWritten;
            } else {
                CloseHandle(ovWrite.hEvent);
                return -1;
            }
        }
        CloseHandle(ovWrite.hEvent);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It seems that it does work now. There are no crashes anymore, at least I can't reproduce them. So as it works now, I'm just asking if what I do is sane, or if I should do things differently.

Comment: Yes, this can be done and this is very commonly done.  Lots of words but no hint whatsoever what you might have done wrong.

Comment: @HansPassant: If I knew what I might have done wrong, I wouldn't ask this question, would I? I can post hundred lines of code if that makes you feel better. I did, however, not find a single source where someone does it the way I need it.

Comment: What's the nature of the crash?

Comment: You have to use `ReadFileEx` for overlapped I/O.

Comment: @JonathanPotter: that is not true. `ReadFile()` supports overlapped I/O as well. The only difference between `ReadFile()` and `ReadFileEx()` is that `ReadFile()` supports both synchronous and asynchronous I/O whereas `ReadFileEx()` only supports asynchronous I/O.

Comment: @OregonGhost: please show your actual code. You are likely not managing the `OVERLAPPED` struct correctly. Have a look at MSDN for an example: [Serial Communication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff802693.aspx).

Comment: @RemyLebeau: I guess so ;) I'll have a look at that example, though I read several of them at MSDN (though I didn't find that one) and also looked at [this code](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2682/Serial-Communication-in-Windows), which I'll likely use if nothing else works (it uses yet another thread though, which I'd like to avoid). I'll post code later this day.

Comment: @CareyGregory: Access Violation 0xC0000005 in the ResetEvent call. I think I'm only getting into this code when the handle was actually signaled (i.e. the WaitCommEvent call completed), but it seems it is too early (or why would it crash at this point?) - at first I had only a single OVERLAPPED for all calls since someone suggested it *should* work, but I switched to separate OVERLAPPEDs for WaitCommEvent, ReadFile and WriteFile, and the crash is when calling ResetEvent on the WaitCommEvent's OVERLAPPED structure, though it is valid at this point, so I guess it's about synchronization...

Comment: I added my code to the question. However, it seems it works correctly now with all the changes I made. Maybe you can still have a look at it to tell me if the code is OK like this.

Comment: Note that we're still experience rare crashes under stress, but currently not on my system. I'm not sure if it's got anything to do with using the buffer outside or resetting the event. It's always either in the ResetEvent call, or from outside the ReadFile call. This seems to happen primarily on slower systems.

Comment: An AV in `ResetEvent()` means the `m_WaitHandle` handle is not valid. Are you absolutely sure that you are calling `ReadData()` via a valid `SerialPort` object instance?

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Yes, and I debugged the calls. The pointers (including the this pointer) are valid, the handle has the value it should have, the OVERLAPPED looks right and so on. I was under the impression that an AV might also happen if resetting an event that is currently being set by the IO system, because it doesn't happen every time. Currently, with my executables, it doesn't even happen on the slow system of a coworker, but for some really, really strange reason, the version built by him from the same source crashes in ResetEvent sometimes :-/

Comment: AVs in random places, especially when changing code to debug it, is likely a good indication that code you have not shown is corrupting memory and your serial code is just the victim of the corruption.

Comment: I thought so too, but when switching the SerialPort implementation back to the previous (which uses 100% CPU for a single thread), everything works fine, even under stress. It always happens with one of the Read/Write calls.

Answer (score 1):

Offhand, I don't see any errors in the code you have shown, but I would like to suggest alternative code to clean up your error handling in `ReadData()` and `WriteData()` in general:

```
int SerialPort::ReadData(void *buffer, int size)
{
    if (fd == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        return 0;

    OVERLAPPED ovRead = {0};
    ovRead.hEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, TRUE, FALSE, NULL);
    if (!ovRead.hEvent)
        return -1;

    DWORD dwBytesRead;
    if (!ReadFile(fd, buffer, size, &dwBytesRead, &ovRead))
    {
        if (GetLastError() != ERROR_IO_PENDING)
        {
            CloseHandle(ovRead.hEvent);
            return -1;
        }

        if (!GetOverlappedResult(fd, &ovRead, &dwBytesRead, TRUE))
        {
            CloseHandle(ovRead.hEvent);
            return -1;
        }
    }

    if (WaitForSingleObject(m_waitHandle, 0) == WAIT_OBJECT_0)
    {
        ResetEvent(m_waitHandle);
        InitWait();
    }

    CloseHandle(ovRead.hEvent);
    return dwBytesRead;
}

int SerialPort::WriteData(const void *buffer, int size)
{
    if (fd == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        return 0;

    OVERLAPPED ovWrite = {0};
    ovWrite.hEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, TRUE, FALSE, NULL);
    if (!ovWrite.hEvent)
        return -1;

    DWORD dwBytesWritten;
    if (!WriteFile(fd, buffer, size, &dwBytesWritten, &ovWrite))
    {
        if (GetLastError() != ERROR_IO_PENDING)
        {
            CloseHandle(ovWrite.hEvent);
            return -1;
        }

        if (!GetOverlappedResult(fd, &ovWrite, &dwBytesWritten, TRUE))
        {
            CloseHandle(ovWrite.hEvent);
            return -1;
        }
    }

    CloseHandle(ovWrite.hEvent);
    return dwBytesWritten;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, the code I wrote was created more or less in a rush, since I was just trying to get things running ;)

Comment: Unfortunately, we're still getting 0xC0000005 crashes on some machines, and mostly in the call to SerialPort::ReadData, sometimes in the ResetEvent call. In all cases I've seen, we were coming from WaitForMultipleObjectsEx from outside, so the event was signalled. ReadData *is* potentially also called by a timer which just checks if there is something there (to avoid telegrams staying in internal buffers until more IO comes). The timer can never trigger at the same time as IO. Can something be potentially inaccessible when leaving Read/WriteData? I expected that the code is synchronous.

Comment: It's rather strange now. I tried disabling the timer, using local buffers instead of the given ones, and we're still crashing. With the code like above, we now mostly crash in `WriteData` in the `GetOverlappedResult` call. `dwBytesWritten` already contains a value at the crash point (like 10 or 17), so it seems `GetOverlappedResult` is ready to return. If we change a few things within the function, the debugger stops outside the `WriteData` call, but has a deep stack to ntdll and KernelBase. It's as if there's something wrong with the stack. There *must* be a problem with this code as it is ;)

Comment: It seems I got it. I re-read all the documentation and came to an interesting thing: WaitCommEvent writes to the dwEventMask I supply. And it does so once the wait completes. But since I made the call in a function, it is gone later - leading to stack corruption. All the examples don't have a problem because they have a dedicated loop with a local variable for that... Will test on the machines where it happened all the time.